# Convert indexes in str to indexes in bytearray

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

I have some text, process it and find offset for some words in text. These offsets will be used by another application and that application operates with text as with sequence of bytes, so str indexes will be wrong for it.

Example:

```
>>> text = "“Hello there!” He said"
>>> text[7:12]
'there'
>>> text.encode('utf-8')[7:12]
>>> b'o the'
```

So how can I convert indexes in string to indexes in encoded bytearray?

Comment: @chrisz No, because there might be other multibyte characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode the substrings and get their lengths in bytes:

```
text = "“Hello there!” He said"
start = len(text[:7].encode('utf-8'))
count = len(text[7:12].encode('utf-8'))
text.encode('utf-8')[start:start+count]
```

This gives `b'there'`.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
def byte_array_index(s, str_index): 
    return len(s[:str_index].encode('utf-8'))
```